# "Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible"

Tags: wcf

I get the error message: Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata when I run the program.  If I remove the ProductClass from Product and comment out assigning value in GetProduct and rerun I am able to run the program.  I need to return som

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://test.com")]
public interface IProducts
{
    [OperationContract]
    Product GetProduct(ProductRequest productRequest);
}
    [ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://test.com")]
public class ProductService : IProducts
{
    public Product GetProduct(ProductRequest productRequest)
    {
        Product product = new Product
        {
            id = 1,
            productName = "Xbox"
        };
        product.productSegment = new ProdSegment()
        {
            id=1,
            segment="Video Games"
        };
        return product;
    }
}
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://test.com")]
public class ProductRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ProductSegment productClass { get; set; }
}
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://test.com")]
public class ProductSegment
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string segment { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]    
public class ProdSegment
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string segment { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string productName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ProdSegment productSegment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I added the appropriate [DataContract] and [DataMember], but I still get the error.

Comment: Note that your last two `DataContracts` - `ProdSegment` and `Product` do not have the namespace set to `http://test.com/` - that might be causing an issue as they will be in a different namespace than the rest of your service (`http://tempuri.org/` is the default if none is assigned).

Comment: Make sure you expose metadata, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that classes used in the service have appropriate `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` applied.
This will allow WCF to generate service metadata. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

**UPDATE** (since you've updated your code example)
You should also make sure you expose metadata for your service. This can be done in two ways:

Enable metadata on your service behavior. By adding this line your service behavior config:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

Or expose metadata endpoint. By adding this line under services/service:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Comment: i have to decorate all the classes with [DataContract(Namespace = "test.com")] for it work.

Comment: Looks like you had namespaces mismatch issue. Making them all the same will definitely fix the problem.